# Unknown xcode sigabrt error with arrays

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

I am writing a simple app in xcode, but whenever I try to run the app in the simulator, I get this:

```
Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

It's crashing at 
    applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
on line 25:
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

My code:

```
- (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSArray * entre = @[ @"Indian", @"American", @"Chinise", @"Italien", @"Japenese", @"Barbeque", @"Breakfast", @"Pizza" ];
    NSArray * dessert = @[ @"Ice Cream", @"Cake", @"Pie", @"Gelato", @"Cupcakes"];
    NSInteger r = arc4random()%8;
     NSInteger f = arc4random()%4;
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:

            [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: entre[r]]];
            break;
        case 1:

            [label setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: dessert[f]]];
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: And don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat:`. Just do `label.text = dessert[f];` for example.

Comment: And you should have a `break` statement for each case, not just the first one.

Comment: Thanks, that's the only error message I see. Sorry xcode noob here, where should I look for it.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Thanks, ready over this now.

Comment: You're not trying to do this in a secondary thread, are you?

Comment: Fixed it, the XIB file was connected to a outlet that did not exist, silly me! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score -1):

well the problem here is you are getting a random number r which can have the value 0-8 and entre[8] is outside the range of array. same for the dessert[f]

Try

```
NSInteger r = arc4random()%7;
NSInteger f = arc4random()%3;
```

Comment: `entre` has 8 elements meaning that the index in the range 0 - 7. A call to `arc4random() % 8` will give a value in the range 0 - 7. And the 2nd range should actually be `arc4random() % 5` since there are 5 elements in the `dessert` array.